# Import MySQL Database on the XAMPP server using PHPscript

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to import a rather large database into my local server (XAMPP) using the following script.

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW

$mysqlDatabaseName ='****';
$mysqlUserName ='****';
$mysqlPassword =*****';
$mysqlImportFilename ='05.03.2014.sql';

//DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -S /tmp/mysql5.sock -p' .$mysqlPassword .' '             .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
    echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to   database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
    break;
case 1:
    echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in   the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database   Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>'    .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
    break;
}
?>
```

However, I keep getting the following error message 
"There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values"

I have a feeling that the hostname might be incorrect - i.e. /tmp/mysql5.sock

Anybody able to help?

Cheers

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BigDump script to import a large database.

[Use "BigDump" script](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try with the phpadmin interface in xampp. I think it pretty easy . And the maximum size for the file can be edited in php.ini .

Comment: I've tried using PHPMyAdmin - changing all of the relevant settings in php.ini but it still keeps timing out. So I'm trying a different approach. I've used the above script on the live server and it works very well, I just can't get it to work with XAMPP.

Comment: You should change the maximum file size & execution time in PHP.ini ... and then restart your xampp ... It should work... I have faced the same issue when I need to upload a big sql file in xampp.

Comment: Change these  max_execution_time and upload_max_filesize